discord.py Bot adds reaction when user adds specific reaction to message
My code already makes it work
Other emojis work fine
But when I use "❤" my code str(emo.emoji) == '❤' return false
I tried using print() to debug
print(type(emo.emoji)) #return str
print(emo.emoji) #return ❤
print(emo.emoji== '❤') #return false
print(str(emo.emoji) == '\u2764') #return false
This is my original code
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(emo,user):
    if str(emo.emoji) == '❤':
        await emo.message.add_reaction(emo)


What about str(emo.emoji) == '\u2764'? Does that return true?

@anjelomerte return false :(
Thanks for reminding me that I forgot to put it up there.

Ok, what does str(emo.emoji) output though?

Return the received emoji.
When I add a "❤" it's a "❤".
add a "" it's a "".
"❤" is not equal to "❤" this is really confusing.

I think I found a solution.
I added an invisible character "❤️" after "❤" and he can recognize it normally.
